# no tasktracker to stop, no namenode to stop localhost:, no datanode to stop localhost

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop on ubuntu using [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) tutorial

I have changed all the conf files and tried every solution available on the internet.
I dont get any error when i run `start-all.sh` but when i use jps to check for processes, I get this:->

```
3132 Jps
2742 SecondaryNameNode
2830 JobTracker
```

when I use `stop-all.sh`, I get:->

```
stopping jobtracker
localhost: no tasktracker to stop
no namenode to stop
localhost: no datanode to stop
localhost: stopping secondarynamenode
```

this is my jobtracker log

```
Problem connecting to HDFS Namenode... re-trying
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
```

Comment: Could you please show me your log files?

Comment: Did you configure SSH settings correctly? as per the tutorial?

Comment: Hi, I am getting the exact same error. Did you solve this problem. Can you please tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check your core-site.xml file to see if you have updated your path to hdfstmp folder. If you have copied and pasted configuration from internet and failed to have configured path, you would get this error. Try something like this:

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/home/user/hdfstmp</value>
</property>
```

Here the hdfstmp is the name of the folder for your default file system.

Once you set your temporary directory in the core-site.xml file correctly, I would suggest

- check all your configuration files once again
- run `bin/stop-all.sh`
- run `hadoop/bin namenode -format`
- run `bin/start-all.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You have to be the owner of the directory containing namenode and datanode.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the port configured for fs.defaultFS property. In my case i had given the port which was already in use. Hence the namenode didnt started. After changing the port i am able to start the name node

Answer (score 0):

1) Use "kill -9 processid"
2) start-all.sh
3) stop-al.sh to verify if stopping the nodes is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Tasktracker doesn't exist for Hadoop **2+**, which you should be using instead of following a blog using Hadoop 1.

As the jps command has shown, there's no active datanode or namenode processes running, so the rest of the output makes sense

> dont get any error when i run start-all.sh

That script hides startup errors. You need to look at the actual namenode and datanode log files to see why they aren't starting